# How can I specify the path to JUnit results from integration tests?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, sonarqube, integration-testing

So I know there is `sonar.junit.reportsPath` that is read by the Java plugin and takes a single directory of XML files to parse.

But what if I do not have one directory of test results, but two, specifically one for unit tests and one for integration tests? The more recent versions of Sonarqube gained some support for reporting coverage of these different test results via `sonar.jacoco.reportPath` and `sonar.jacoco.itReportPath`. I also find some references on the internet about `sonar.junit.itReportsPath`, but not in the official documentation or sources, so I guess its unsupported.

TL;DR - where can I specify the path to integration test results?

Software: Sonarqube 5.1.1,
Sonarqube-Runner 2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not available. Feel free to vote for https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-4101

Comment: So what are the alternatives? Copying all XML files into one location before executing Sonar?

Comment: I'm now doing exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

Quite old, but in case someone else come through while searching a solution: I finally changed the output folder of the failsafe plugin to the folder of the surefire plugin. So both tests are parsed and counted in SQ.

```
<!-- write to surefire folder, so sonarqube can fetch and count tests -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
    <configuration>
         <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```