# Does maven sonarqube plugin reads failsafe reports?

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, maven-failsafe-plugin

I am using 3.6 maven sonar plugin . While seeing with `mvn sonar:sonar -X` , I did not see sonar searching for failsafe report. (Finding it or not finding it is different thing )

According to this [doc](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+Unit+Tests+and+Coverage+Results+Import) , I think it cannot be configured for failsafe reports for integration test.

Does `mvn sonar:sonar` reads failsafe reports ? If yes , how ?

I have mentioned these properties in my POM:

```
    <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>/Users/xxx/site-order/service/target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
    <sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>/Users/xxx/site-order/service/target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>
    <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
    <sonar.junit.itReportsPath>/Users/xxx/site-order/service/target/failsafe-reports</sonar.junit.itReportsPath>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the [same question on sonarqube](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/does-sonarqube-maven-plugin-be-configured-to-read-failsafe-reports/9515/2?u=breakingbenjamin) forum and I got the reply that there is no such direct support in sonarqube maven plugin. Also, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33390051/how-can-i-specify-the-path-to-junit-results-from-integration-tests).